# Delphi XE2; Clipboard and animated Gifs

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I show animated gifs in my delphi form as follows:

```
(UnsupportedGif.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).AnimateLoop := glEnabled;
(UnsupportedGif.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := true;
```

When the user clicks on the `Timage` I want to copy the animated gif to the clipboard but I can't get it right. This is what I've tried:

```
Clipboard.Assign(UnsupportedGif.Picture.Graphic);
```

No error message appears and nothing is copied to the clipboard. Can somebody point out to me how to do it right?

Comment: `TGIFImage` supports the clipboard.  It saves data in `CF_GIF` format (registered via `RegisterClipboard('GIF Image')`). How exactly are you checking that nothing is copied to the clipboard? Are you using an actual Clipboard Viewer app, or are you simply pasting into an app? Maybe the app you are pasting into does not support `CF_GIF` data so it gets ignored.

Comment: thx for your answer CMW.

I'm just pasting it into an app (lotus notes, that support animated gifts, i'm not sure about CF-GIF format) but nothing. 

Is there another way to check it? or there is another way to copy it into the clipboard?

Comment: There is no standardized format for storing an animated GIF onto the clipboard. `TGifImage` uses `RegisterClipboardFormat()` to register a custom format ID, which is then used when copy/pasting GIFs between `TGifImage` objects. Unless apps are specifically coded to recognize that particular format ID, it is unlikely that you will be able to copy/paste animated GIFs to non-VCL apps using the code you showed.

Comment: That being said, there are tools/APIs available to look at what is currently on the clipboard, so you could try having Lotus copy an animated GIF onto the clipboard, then you can extract its format ID and change your code to call `TGifImage.SaveToClipboardFormat()`, change the ID, and then call `TClipboard.SetBuffer()` or `TClipboard.SetAsHandle()` directly.